# Thin clients without power supply

Tags: hardware, thin-client

Workplace has no power. Is it possible to work thin clients without power supply?

Comment: Sorry I just have to ask..... is this a joke?

Answer (score 3):

a few ideas:

- portable computers: laptops, netbooks.
- handheld devices: smartphones, tablets, Nokia N700-N810
- very low power mainboards (VIA or ARM) hooked to an UPS.

In the end, you'll always need some power:

- for the server (unless it's remote)
- for the network (switches, access points, router if server is remote)
- to recharge batteries (either internal or on UPS)

If you try to go PoE, note that the distance is limited; Ethernet UTP itself goes up to 150m, but to get PoE at high wattage more than 50-70m you need higher voltages at the source.  A lot easier would be to lay your own power cable as you do the network.

tl;dr: electronic devices use electricity.  might be low amounts of it, but never zero.

Answer (score 2):

Computers need power. There's really no way around that.

Answer (score -1):

If you found computer with 15 Wt consumption.. PoE can give you only 15 Wt... I don't see any another way...

Comment: And what is going to power the PoE?

Comment: Hamsters in wheels! Or an exercise bike?

Comment: it's not hard to find linux-capable ARM boards that consume far less than 15W (heck, even some VIA boards fit!).  the _huge_ problem would be to power the display.

Comment: @John Gardeniers: assuming the server does have power available, you could power the switch at that central location.

Comment: PoE+ can provide 25,5 watts